# How to disable Keyboard suggestions on EditText and tell the keyboard to show extra number row

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an EditText in my layout file. When I click(focus) on EditText a soft keyboard appear contains predictive word in keyboard suggestion bar(see figure 1).

### Figure 1

[image: keyboard with suggestion bar]
But I want that when I will click on my EditText keyboard will appear with no suggestion bar and with an extra number row(see Figure 2).

### Figure 2

[image: keyboard with no suggestion bar and with extra number row]
I already tried some answer saying that adding below attribute will do that but none of them seems worked for me.
`inputType="text|textNoSuggestion"`,`inputType="textFilter"` not worked.
The below code work but also open a secure keyboard.(oppo,vivo phone built in feature)

```
inputType="textNoSuggestion|textVisiblePassword"
```

Is there any solution to make it done without opening secure keyboard?
**N.B.** I don't wanna disable the secure keyboard.
I saw this feature on some code editing application available on playstore.

Answer (score 0):

Add this after intialalizing EditText

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

Then add TextWatcher to handle input changes

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            // Check if the EditText is empty 
            if (editable.toString().isEmpty()) {
                editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
            }
       }
 });
```

hope it works